# Can't bind to Property Xsince it isn't a known property of Child Component

Tags: angular

The error is:

NG8002: Can't bind to 'setNumber' since it isn't a known property of 'app-game-control'.

1. If 'app-game-control' is an Angular component and it has 'setNumber' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-game-control' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

**Why he can not find a setNumber in gameControler?**

import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-game-control',
  templateUrl: './game-control.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./game-control.component.css'],
})
export class GameControlComponent {
  incresNumber: number = 0;
  @Output() setNumber: any;
  // start the game and increse number every time by one and send back to parant comp. data
  startGame() {
    console.log(this.setNumber);
    setInterval(() => {
      this.setNumber.emit(this.incresNumber++);
      this.incresNumber++;
    }, 1000);
  }
  endGame() {}
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="container">
  <app-game-control [setNumber]="incresNumber()"></app-game-control>
</div>
```

Comment: Is `GameControlComponent` declared in your `AppModule`? It would be helpful if you could provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing your problem in an online code editor such as [Stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com).

Comment: Yes it is declared in AppModul

Comment: `@Output` in the template is an event, so it should be bound with `()`, instead of `[]`